# Using Jquery,Can anyone help me with highlighting color of date(In a week view) in full calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got new requirement,Using  Jquery,Can anyone help me with highlighting color of date(In a week view) in full calendar,when date got selected by a Datepicker.

```
$(document) .ready(function () {
        $(function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            onSelect: function(dateText,inst){  

            var vals  = dateText.split("/"),eventDate =new Date(Number(vals[2]),Number(vals[1]), Number(vals[0]));
            //this.dayhighlight = eventDate;
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', Number(vals[2]), Number(vals[1])-1, Number(vals[0]));  

            var eventDate1 =new Date(Number(vals[2]),Number(vals[1])-1,Number(vals[0]));

            var reqDate = new Date(eventDate1);  
            var dd = reqDate.getDate();
            var mm = reqDate.getMonth()+1;
            var yyyy = reqDate.getFullYear();                 

            dayRender: function(daysOfWeek, cell){                 

                 if(reqDate.getDate()==daysOfWeek.getDate())
                  {
                      $(cell).addClass('fc-state-highlight');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $(cell).removeClass('fc-state-highlight');
                  }
              }     
           }

        });  

       });
   });
```

My code functionality is working.It is going to that particular date in a WeekView in FullCalendar but I am unable to highlight that cell color of the date,I am using JQuery v1,here trying to use dayRender() but it is not working,Can anyone help with me this please.

Answer (score 0):

You put the `dayRender` property within the `onSelect` function of the `datepicker`. This will probably crash(check your console) as you can't set a `fullCalendar` property within a callback function of `datepicker`.

You code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // first set the selected date to null so there is no highlighted date
    var selected_date = null;

    // initialize the calendar (including the dayRender callback)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
        dayRender: function(date, cell){ 
            if (selected_date == $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date)){
                $(cell).addClass('fc-highlight');
            }
        }
    });

    // initialize the date picker
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function( dateText, inst ) {
            // when the date changes, we update the selected_date
            var date = new Date(dateText);
            selected_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            // call the goToDate method on fullCalendar
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
            // call render on calendar (so that the dayRender is called and the selected date is highlighted
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'); 
        }
    });     
});
```

Here is an solution:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/vqqk4/28/)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for ur suggestion.Yeah,I need to correct on that,but after trying above code,today and next buttons iare getting added redundantly.I need date to get highlighted in weekmode. Can u suggest some better function?